# useCallback & useMemo are con's in functional components when compared to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, usecallback

In functional components, will the usage of useCallback and useMemo hooks cause performance issue when compared to class component implementation as these are some extra checks react has to do.

So are class components better than functional components in this case?

Comment: Until you can measure a significant performance issue, which is unlikely going to be caused by hooks or a couple function instantiations, it's pointless to compare classes and function components over their performance difference.

Comment: Hi Emile, I am not aware about the implementation or at least abstract implementation of useMemo or useCallback. According to my knowledge for functional components to work React needs to maintain some kind of memory to remember about components between renders and do the referential equality check. So, you mean this might not cause much impact?

Comment: What I mean is that without a concrete example proving a performance issue, there's nothing to discuss.